# Convert string to date SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, business-intelligence

I have issue converting parameter string to date.

I have list of data as:

```
Jul 28 2017  Call
Jan  8 2018  SMS
Apr 24 2018  Call
Jul  2 2018  E-Mail
Jul 13 2018  Call
Oct  1 2018  Call
Nov 27 2018  E-Mail
Dec 31 2018  Call
Jan  1 2019  SMS
Apr  1 2019  SMS
Jun  4 2019  SMS
```

I want them to be presented as eg. 06/04/2019 if possible

I tried `LSet(Format(Parameters!DateInfo.Label,"MM/dd/yyyy"),12)` in expression, but when I run the report it is showing me just like this MM/dd/YYYY.

Comment: Why is your column, which is clearly a date, not a date and time date type in the first place? Then changing the formatting is trivial as you just change the Format property of the cell is it displayed in. Seems like you should be fixing the dataset, not the report.

Comment: Well, if the value is a string then no the format property won't work. As I mentioned, fix the dataset and make the column a date (and time) data type; it is date after after all, so it should be strongly typed.

Comment: DataSet is just fine. I have to combine two columns in one for the parameter and from Parameter to take value just of date

Comment: *"DataSet is just fine."* If you are passing a date and time value as a string to the report, it's not "fine". If is it fine, then the column will be correct typed as a date and time data type and just changing the format property to `MM/dd/yyyy` will work.

Comment: Why can't you relay the data in 2 columns? I've never seen it done like this which should be an indication to you that this isn't the right way of doing things.

Answer (score 2):

For your parameter, you probably should be using a dataset for the dates with the Value set to use a date field and the Label using the string representation of the date (`CONVERT(CHAR(10), THEDATE, 110) AS DATE_LABEL`).

I'm guessing the user isn't typing the parameter values in which means that there's already a dataset for the dates. Add another column to the dataset with the date as a date field to use as the Value while using the text as the Label.

If you cannot fix that and still need to convert the text field into a date, you could use the **CDATE** function which will convert text into a date field.

```
=Format(CDATE(LEFT(Parameters!DateInfo.Label, 12)),"MM/dd/yyyy")
```